# Duplicating stdout to stderr

Tags: bash, redirect

I'd like to have the stdout of a command replicated to stderr as well under bash. Something like:

```
$ echo "FooBar" (...)
FooBar
FooBar
$
```

where (...) is the redirection expression. Is that possible?

Comment: See [How can I send stdout to multiple commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use tee with /dev/stderr:

```
echo "FooBar" | tee /dev/stderr
```

or use awk/perl/python to manually do the replication:

```
echo "FooBar" | awk '{print;print > "/dev/stderr"}'

echo "FooBar" | perl -pe "print STDERR, $_;"
```

Comment: unneeded comma after STDERR in perl example

Comment: which is more portable across OSes and across Shells? `tee /dev/stderr` or `tee >(cat >&2)` ?

Comment: I'd wager the latter is more cross-platform compatible seeing as how `/dev/stderr` isn't available on every distro.

Comment: `tee /dev/stderr` does not work for systemd service, because fd 2 is a socket instead of fifo. This is documented at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=.

Comment: `tee /dev/stderr` also doesn't work if current user doesn't have "write" permission to the controlling terminal. This happens for example if you login to another non-root user via "su" or "sudo"

Answer (score 31):

Use process substitution: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

`echo "FooBar" | tee >(cat >&2)`

Tee takes a filename as parameter and duplicates output to this file. With process substitution you can use a process instead of filename `>(cat)` and you can redirect the output from this process to stderr `>(cat >&2)`.

Comment: This is a good solution for operating systems like OS X, which does not have the /proc file system.

Comment: This is better than relying on /dev/stderr, as it may not be writable, as shown by defdefred.

Comment: On many OS's, you may not even need to use `cat`. (i.e. `echo "FooBar" | tee >(>&2)`)

Answer (score 2):

If I may expand [@defdefred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141738/duplicating-stdout-to-stderr/49069684#49069684), for multiple lines I'm using

```
my_commmand | while read line; do echo $line; echo $line >&2; done
```

It has the "advantage" of not requiring / calling `tee` and using built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "FooBar" |tee /dev/stderr
tee: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
```

not working with RedHat 6.3

```
echo "FooBar" | ( read A ; echo $A ; echo $A >&2)
```

is working

Comment: sorry, explanation added ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting to stderr, I would use `>&2` or `>/dev/stderr`. For replicating output, I would use `tee`. The drawback of it is that a temporary file is needed:

```
echo "FooBar" | tee /tmp/stdout >&2 ; cat /tmp/stdout
```

Comment: wrong. you have a chance to get big flow and completly fill /tmp device, usually connected to /root filesystem.

Comment: @Znik - `/tmp/stdout` is just an example. Feel free to replace that filename with whatever is more appropriate in your context.