# Bash: How to direct output to both stderr and to stdout, to pipe into another command?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I know variations of this question have been asked and answered [several times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file), but I'm either misunderstanding the solutions, or am trying to do something eccentric. My instinct is that it shouldn't require `tee` but maybe I'm completely wrong...

Given a command like this:

```
sh
echo "hello"
```

I want to send it to STDERR so that it can be logged/seen on the console, *and* so that it can be sent to another command. For example, if I run:

```
sh
echo "hello" SOLUTION>&2 > myfile.txt
```

(`SOLUTION>` being whatever the answer to my problem is)

I want:

- `hello` to be shown in the console like any other STDERR message
- The file `myfile.txt` to contain `hello`

Comment: AFAIK, bash stream redirection cannot duplicate a stream. That's the whole point of `tee`'s existence. And as far as I can see, your question is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to redirect it to `stderr`. Just use `tee` to send it to the file while also sending to `stdout`, which will go to the terminal.

```
echo "hello" | tee myfile.txt
```

If you want to pipe the output to another command without writing it to a file, then you could use

```
echo "hello" | tee /dev/stderr | other_command
```

You could also write a shell function that does the equivalent of `tee /dev/stderr`:

```
$ tee_to_stderr() {
    while read -r line; do
        printf "%s\n" "$line";
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >&2
    done
}

$ echo "hello" | tee_to_stderr | wc
hello
       1       1       6
```

This doesn't work well with binary output, but since you intend to use this to display text on the terminal that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen some variation of this answer, but with the caveat that not all systems have `/dev/stderr` and I was wondering what it would look like using the stderr file descriptor. On the other hand, the lack of universal standard on `/dev/stderr` is not a huge concern of mine so this answer works just as well for me.

Comment: The shell doesn't have any built-in mechanism for replicating output to multiple fds. And tee doesn't have an option for writing directly to an fd. You could write a shell function that does it.

Answer (score 1):

`tee` copies stdin to the files on its command line, and also to stdout.

```
echo hello | tee myfile.txt >&2
```

This will save `hello` in `myfile.txt` and also print it to stderr.